Android studio error java.lang.NullPointerException (JetpackCompose)
I've begun delving into Room database within Jetpack Compose by crafting a simple example. However, I'm currently facing an issue and I'm unable to pinpoint the source of the error(java.lang.NullPointerException). I would greatly appreciate some assistance. Below are all of my codes. Thank you.
[[[[[[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/ekKUV0vI.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/TMHvbY7J.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/Jp9zMCn2.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/47EEFQLj.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/e8ozEBDv.jpg)](https://i.sstatic.net/wCacKbY8.jpg)
I'm in search of a solution and have been watching videos for examples, but many of them are quite advanced. I'm specifically seeking straightforward examples that demonstrate saving data and checking it.

You need to provide the code as text, not as screenshots. Also, please reduce your code to a minimal reproducible example. We do not want to see "all of my codes", just the relevant parts. You can edit your question to remove the screenshots and add the code as text. Make sure to properly format the code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
